# access form in directive via the parent controller

Tags: angularjs

main.html

```
<div ng-controller="myCtrl">
  ....
  <direcitve here>
</div>
```

directive.html

```
<form name="myForm">
  <input name="inputOne" ng-model="formData.one" required>
  <input name="inputTwo" ng-model="formData.two" required>
  <input name="inputThree" ng-model="formData.three" required>
</form>
```

I'm trying to access a form in a directive via the controller like so:
`controller.js

$scope.myform`

but I keep getting `undefined`.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried creating an empty object in the controller (`$scope.foo = {}`) and using `name="foo.myForm"`?

Comment: this worked. Is it common practice to create an object like so?  Haven't seen it in the docs.

Comment: Yes, it's common practice. That's why it's advised to always have a dot in your ngModel: if the input is inside a directive that creates its own scope, and you don't have a dot in the ngModel, then the model will be written in the directive scope rather than the controller scope. See https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes. Since the whole form here is inside such a directive, and you want to access the form from the controller, you can use the same trick.